# regular sequence $\iff$ complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ a closed subscheme of dimension $n-r$.
We say $X$ is complete intersection if $X = V(I)$, where $I$ is a homogeneous ideal which is generated by $r$ elements.

Next, for a closed immersion of locally noetherian schemes $f : X \to Y$, we say that $f$ is a regular immersion of codimension $r$ if at every point $x \in X$, the kernel of $f^\#_x : \mathscr{O}_{Y, f(x)} \to \mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ is generated by a regular sequence of $r$ elements.

Now for $Y = \mathbb{P}^n$ and $i: X \to Y$, are these two conditions equivalent?
In example 3.5. of Liu's "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves", the author says that a complete intersection is a regular immersion in this situation.

To show this, I think it's sufficient to show that:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian local integral domain of dimension $n$, $I$ a proper ideal and suppose that $\dim A/I = n-r$. Then if $I$ is generated by $r$ elements, then $I$ is generated by a regular sequence of $r$ elements.

For our purpose we can assume that $A$ is regular and is finitely generated over a field.

I showed that for a generator $f_1, \dots, f_r$, $\dim A/(f_1, \dots, f_i) = n-i$.
So $f_{i+1}$ in $A/(f_1, \dots, f_i)$ is not contained in any minimal prime ideal.
Therefore if these $A/(f_1, \dots, f_i)$ are reduced, this sequence is a regular sequence.
And by [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07DV), it seems that we can assume these rings reduced.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The highlighted part is wrong unless $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay. A counterexample is given by $A=K[[X^4,X^3Y,XY^3,Y^4]]$, and $I=(X^4,Y^4)$.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for your comment. So, if $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay, is it true? If so could you show me a proof?

Comment: When $A$ is CM we have $\mathrm{grade}(I)=\dim A-\dim A/I=r$, and if $I=(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ we get that $a_1,\dots,a_r$ is an $A$-sequence. (No need to assume $A$ domain.)

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much!